# Bootstrap modal inside iframe to have opacity applied over parent frame as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

We have this bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="divModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalPrincipal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <center>
                    <div class="modal-header" style="width:95%;text-align:left;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title lead" id="modalPrincipal">Copiar permisos de otro usuario:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Seleccione un usuario:

                        <select id="listaUsuarios" name="listaUsuarios" style="margin-left:4px; margin-bottom:14px;">
                            <option>Cargando...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonCopiar" onclick="copiarPermisos();">Copiar</button>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the modal opens a background is displayed behind the modal with an opacity level. Here's the div that boostraps seems to add automatically:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"> ...
```

The problem is this background is displayed only over the iframe but we would need it to cover the whole website (including parent frame).

Comment: An IFrame is not different to a totally different website, with a totally independent DOM.  So I don't believe it's possible.  But instead of an IFrame, you could just use a DIV instead and load the DIV.  This is then using the same DOM..

Comment: Hi Keith, How would I use a Div instead of an iframe?

Comment: There are lot's of ways of doing this, but a simple way would be using `jquery.load()`..  http://api.jquery.com/load/